# C# - Struggling to access variables for object within a list

Tags: c#

I'm have tried looking around for a solution but to no avail.

Why can't i access any of the variables within the created items in the list

(inv.inventory[i].Name as seen near the bottom)

If needed i can post all my code although it is 569 lines.

```html
public class Item
{
    //All Item Attributes
}

public class PotionHP : Item
{
    // Specific Attributes
    public string Name = "HP Potion";
    public string Desc = "Restores HP by 10.";
    public int Cost = 8;
    public int Modifier = 10;
}

public class PotionAT : Item
{
    // Specific Attributes
    public string Name = "AT Potion";
    public string Desc = "Restores Attack by 1.";
    public int Cost = 8;
    public int Modifier = 10;
}

public class Revive : Item
{
    // Specific Attributes
    public string Name = "Revive";
    public string Desc = "Revives upon death with 5 HP.";
    public int Cost = 8;
    public int Modifier = 10;
}
        
public class Inventory
{
    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();

    public Inventory()
    {
        inventory.Add(new PotionHP());
        inventory.Add(new PotionAT());
        inventory.Add(new PotionHP());
        inventory.Add(new Revive());
     }
}

for (int i = 0; i < inv.inventory.Count; i++)
{
    //Why can't i access inv.inventory[i].Name?
    Console.WriteLine($"{inv.inventory[i].Name}");
}
```

Comment: Every class has same specific attributes. Why don't add all fields in base class and in derived classes only assign them specific value?

Comment: You need to provide the `Name` property in the base class `Item`. The child constructor should call the base constructor with the `Name`. Then make this property readonly to avoid that it will be changed later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't have `Name` field in base class. Move it to base class. Also I recommend to use properties instead of public fields:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also seems like you don't need inheritance here. You just providing values to base class fields. You can use Creation Methods for that.

Of course, you can use other options to create items with predefined field values. But anyway - **you don't need new classes if your 'classes' differ only by values of fields**. You need different instances of one class in that case.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public int Modifier { get; set; }

    public static Item CreatePotionAT()
    {
        return new Item
        {
           Name = "AT Potion",
           Desc = "Restores HP by 10.",
           Cost = 8,
           Modifier = 10
        };
    }

    // etc
}
```

Or even:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Desc { get; }
    public int Cost { get; }
    public int Modifier { get; }

    public Item(string name, string desc, int cost, int modifier)
    {
        Name = name;
        Desc = desc;
        Cost = cost;
        Modifier = modifier;
    }

    public static Item CreatePotionHP()
    {
        return new Item("HP Potion","Restores HP by 10.", 8, 10);
    }

    // etc
}
```

And inventory:

```
public Inventory()
{
    inventory = new List<Item>
    {
       Item.CreatePotionHP(), // creation method
       new Item("AT Potion","Restores Attack by 1.", 8, 10), // constructor
       Item.CreatePotionHP(),
       new Item("Revive","Revives upon death with 5 HP.", 8, 10)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Simple OOPS isn't it :), Item doesn't know what Name is, but Children know about it, another option is to Typecast into Child class and use it, though better to have a common property in base class and just assign values in the child class

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yep, just wrote that comment :)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the silly mistakes, i'm very new to C# :)

Answer (score 1):

You are dangling around the inheritance that you are using. Up to now the inheritance from `Item` does not have any advantage. Since all your children classes have the same parameters you can simply write the properties into the base class and leave only the initialization in the constructors of the derived classes:

```
public class Item
{

    public string Name = "HP Potion";
    public string Desc = "Restores HP by 10.";
    public int Cost = 8;
    public int Modifier = 10;

    //All Item Attributes
}
public class PotionHP : Item
{
    public PotionHP()
    {
        // Specific Attributes
        Name = "HP Potion";
        Desc = "Restores HP by 10.";
        Cost = 8;
        Modifier = 10;
    }
}
public class PotionAT : Item
{
    public PotionAT()
    {
        Name = "AT Potion";
        Desc = "Restores Attack by 1.";
        Cost = 8;
        Modifier = 10;
    }
}
public class Revive : Item
{
    public Revive()
    {
        // Specific Attributes
        Name = "Revive";
        Desc = "Revives upon death with 5 HP.";
        Cost = 8;
        Modifier = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete fields in derived classes. You just hide fields from base class. You should initialize all fields in constructor or method.

Comment: @Roma was just at the moment editing, when you wrote your comment :)

Comment: You can't initialize inherited fields directly in class. Do it in constructor.

Comment: @Roma thank you for pointing out, a fast shot, is not always a precise one